# Finding equation of curve for NTC type thermistor

Tags: arduino, thermistor, graph, data-acquisition, equation

I have an NTC thermistor from the KTM 390 engine which I am trying to interface with the Arduino MEGA. The problem is the sensor has no datasheet. I have got the relation between the temperature vs resistance for the thermistor form another person working on the same project. 
[image]

I did plot a curve for the points in MS excel and tried getting a function using trendline feature but the equation couldn't map the curve entirely. I have also tried using different websites for curve fitting but the result was the same as earlier.
I need help to form an equation for the above set of points and establish a relation between temperature and resistance. I will use this equation in my Arduino program to get the temperature for the corresponding resistance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not specifically about EE. Hint - try harder using excel to generate a three or four term polynomial (or get a thermistor with a decent data sheet).

Comment: If it has no datasheet, don't use it.

Comment: You can effectively extract the necessary information using the Beta equation or the Steinhart - Hart equation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor

Comment: A long time ago I was able to do this using the [R](https://www.r-project.org) package and some guidance, such as [Dave Tang's blog](https://davetang.org/muse/2013/05/09/on-curve-fitting/).

Comment: You might want to look over this thread:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/472611/thermistor-scavenge-from-digital-medical-thermometer/472625#472625

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the resistance appears to be [roughly] exponential, take the log before curve fitting. If a third order is not accurate enough for your needs, you may need to go to a higher order, or collect data outside the range you measured (accuracy is worst at the ends).

Edit: solved for the wrong variable the first time, try this...

[image]

Formulas:

[image]

Comment: The resistance-temperature relationship for a thermistor is not an exponential, though that is close for a restricted temperature range.

Comment: @SteveSh - Yes, not exponential, roughly exponential in shape. Log *plus* curve fit works fairly well, third order calculation is within 0.16 degrees.

Comment: @SteveSh - just saw your equation in the link in the comments. So, taking the reciprocal of the temp before curve fitting might work better.

Answer (score 1):

An other solution can be to load the values into an array in matlab
define the generic function Spehro Pefhany posted and use least squares to do the fitting as it's shown [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/280276-trying-to-find-best-fit-for-cosine-curve) for a cosine, but the logic is the same for everything

also you can use the [interactive toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/curve-fitting.html)

although by using the first solution and making a proper script you have a fitter for all devices with a behavior described by that particular function

Answer (score 0):

One typical approximation for the NTC thermistor is [Steinhart-Hart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhart%E2%80%93Hart_equation):

\$ \frac{1}{T} = A + B\cdot \ln{(R)} + C\cdot (\ln{(R)})^3 \$

I believe you can get a pretty good approximation from the first two terms, but I have used all three below:

Use absolute temperature for T.

If I substitute in the closed-form solution for T= 0°C, 70°C, 130°C I get agreement that is within about +/-0.2°C at all of the specified temperature points in the table.

- A = 0.001304625
- B = 0.000258513
- C = 1.71064E-07

Given the low number of significant digits of the resistances and the likely accuracy of the NTC that's more than good enough.

Note that the 3-point formula means that the function has **zero** error at the three points you pick, so you would typically want to pick the two extremes that are available (so as to avoid extrapolation) and for the third a point close to the typical operating point or near the center of the operating range.